# How can I check if a .war is deployed

Tags: java, war

I have deployed a .war file with the following command:

```
java -jar myfile.war
```

what is the command to check if the file is deployed and running?

Comment: In which server you are deployed.

Comment: java -jar runs a file, it does not deploy anything. However it is possible that you have a special .war that is runnable, but you would need to provide more details.

Comment: `java -jar` won't deploy war-files as those are meant to be deployed to a webserver/application server such as Tomcat and the command wouldn't know where that server is. Normally they either provide some UI to deploy and check war files or you just place them into a special deployment directory.

Comment: I am deploying it to a Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 2):

WARs are not deployed like this by default. They are intended originally to be put into some kind of servers (like Tomcat). This means physically putting the file into some predefined folders.

Since you obviously don't work like this, its kind of not-enough information to provide a server specific answer.

So I'll provide only general ways:

**Option 1**

Run an HTTP request (you can even create a special "/health" endpoint). Then just call this request and if it responds with something that you expect to receive, then the war is deployed.

**Option 2**

When the War is deployed programmatically create some kind of listener where you can LOG something on console / create a file on filesystem that will denote that the service is up and running.